# android Html.fromHtml() doesn't give highlighted text every time

Tags: android, html

When I use the `Html.fromHtml()` in android it gives me highlighted text but only for few colors. basically it returns the highlighted text for Red,blue, green and maroon. it doesn't work with all colors like yellow and others. can anyone answer why this happens? I am using `Html.fromHtml()` to set highlighted colors to textview

```
    TextView tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.mytext);

    tv.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color='red'>highlight this </font>")); //This works
    tv.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color='yellow'>highlight this </font>")); //This does not work
```

I have created an android library which takes the words and highlights each word with different color but it does't work for all colors.

Comment: *can anyone answer why this happens?* actually, no, without sample html

Comment: do you have to use `Html.fromHtml`? cannot you use `Spannable`?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. This would include the HTML, the Java code that is trying to use HTML, and an explanation of what "it doesn't work" means.

Comment: Try using **rgb** colors, instead of **named** ones.

Comment: using HEX values solved my problem, RGB values also works.

Answer (score -1):

try using Spannable, check below code

```
    String msg = "Delivery available at pincode: ";
    SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(msg);
    ClickableSpan span1 = new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View textView) {
           // 
        }

        @Override
        public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
            super.updateDrawState(ds);           
            ds.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            // or use any color code 
            ds.setColor(Color.parseColor("#d84c4c"));
            ds.setUnderlineText(false);

        }
    };


  ss.setSpan(span1, 0, msg.length() - 1, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

  mPincode.setText(ss);
```

now here i have added only one span, you can add more than one span in one sentence and give different styles and actions by specifying starting and ending position of letter in sentence.